# wp_insert_post generating duplicate id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I use following code to generate id for a product variation.

```
$i = 0; 
while($i < 2){ // 2 is example
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
 $variation_post = array(
    'post_title'  => 'Variation #' . $i . ' of ' . $product->get_name(),
    'post_name'   => 'product-'.$product_id.'-variation',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => $product_id,
    'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
    'guid'        => $product->get_permalink()
 );
    
 if((post_exists('Variation #' . $i . ' of ' . $product->get_name())) == 0){
    $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );
 }
 $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

 $i++;
}
```

but the `wp_insert_post` generating two ids instead one . I use this code in ajax file,
where is the problem?!

Comment: Nobody can answer this question, until you show us the complete hooked function and related code that shows how you are using it… *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem***." See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What's happening is that your code is running and running in a loop. You're not checking if the product variation exist first, before injecting a post or a page you should always check if it exist first.

Comment: @amarinediary My code usage answers are not made specifically for your usage, so you need to adapt any picked code to your needs… Now your question here is still unclear and not answerable as nobody can guess how you are using your provided code.

Comment: @amarinediary I edite the question and add counter $i then use post_exists to check if post exist based on title. Condition works correctly but again in woocomerce product edit section there are duplicated product variation!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Dear my friend. The problem was in calling the js file. Unfortuanately I call it twice :P it's about two days that I stuck to it. Thanks you alot for the function. Be lucky my friend :)